# Чи нормативне слово пляцок?

Tags: вживання-слів

Мабуть всі на західній Україні знають різницю між пляцками та тортами. Та в СУМі нема слова пляцок. Натомість безліч [інтернет-ресурсів](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%BA) пояснюють що це таке. Чи є нормативним застосування даного слова, якщо його нема в словниках?

Answer (score 2):

[Словник галицького діалекту](http://www.aratta-ukraine.com/text_ua.php?id=2291)

> Пляцки (пляцок) – солодкий пиріг або деруни, картопляники

[Словник uk.WorldwideDictionary.org](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%BA) (імовірно, передрук [«Словників України on-line» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/))

> (корж) [діал.]
>
> [image]

[Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови](http://padaread.com/?book=50054&pg=995)

> ПЛЯЦОК пляцка, ч., зах. Корж

Слово ***"пляцок"*** хоча і присутнє в декількох словниках, але з позначкою діалеткне, і тому не є нормативним.

Answer (score 1):

Слово *пляцок* наводить як відповідник російського *колобок, лепешка* [Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%BA&scope=all&dicts=1&highlight=on), як синонім іменника *дерун* -  [Російсько-український народний сучасний словник 2009–](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%BA&scope=all&dicts=10&highlight=on). Отже, приводів сумніватися в його нормативності недостатньо.